# During performance testing using JMeter Tool - Not able to encrypt the input values using javascript in JSR223 and hybrid-crypto.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223

Greetings...!

During the performance test scripting using JMeter tool : I am trying to access "hybrid-crypto.js" which I have saved in JMeter bin folder. But I am getting an error as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0IYQ.png) - Help me in fixing this issue & confirm me if my approach is correct?

Developer has built the encryption logic is in NodeJs and I have converted into JavaScript using JSR223 Preprocessor to encrypt the input data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is not something which is present in [Nashorn engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) as it is specific to a **web browser**, you won't be able to execute this code in a JSR223 Test Element because it doesn't implement browser at all.

Also be informed that the [recommended scripting option for JMeter is Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so you should rather "convert" the encryption logic into Groovy, not into JavaScript.

More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In JMeter by Groovy can we encrypt input data in conjunction with hybrid-crypto.js?